# How to make bootstrap affect only a part of an html document

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to integrate my web application inside another(main app). I don't use the bootstrap library but the main app does. I however don't want my already-styled controls to be affected by the bootstrap of the main app. How can I prevent bootstrap from applying its styles on my controls?

Comment: don't include bootstrap.css in your app's `<header>`

Comment: Don't use Bootstrap related files where you don't need :)

Comment: Well the main app is a single page app. My app is going to be included under one option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really. If the CSS overwrites the styling of basic elements the only way for you to not be affected by them is to override the changes (each and every attribute) on your portion of the ui and below.

It is in my humble opinion, one of the weakest points of CSS today that you have no way to block the cascading when desired.

Comment: I was not active in this community when I asked this question and today I realized how important it is to accord someone for his contribution. -Cheers